# Citing references with the footcites command results in weird indention of the footnote from second line onwards

Tags: footnotes

Currently I use these setting to customize my footnote formatting. If I statically put the reference in a footnote using the defined fn command the resulting footnote is algigned. How can I achieve this with the footcite command?

```
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{1.3em}
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\footnote{\hangpara{1.635em}{1} #1}}
\newcommand{\fnt}[1]{\footnotetext{\hangpara{1.635em}{1} #1}}
```

If an MWE is required, I'll gladly post the preamble here.

When I have only onle one line per footnote, all works fine, but whenever I encounter a longer footnote spanning more than one line, from the second line onwards, the footnote gets flushed all the way to the left margin and is not vertically aligned with the beginning of the first line (right of the footnote index), see below picture footnote nr. 71 for reference.

[image]

I would highly appreciate any pointer. Thank you all!

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % new

\usepackage[a4paper,top=20mm,bottom=10mm,left=20mm,right=50mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{appendix}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{6pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt} 
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\captionsetup{justification=justified}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

% \usepackage{mathtools}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, autocite=footnote, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=99, sorting=nyt, sortcites=false, giveninits=true, dashed=false, uniquename=init, url=true, isbn=false, doi=false, urldate=ymd, hyperref=true, backref=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
urlseen={Accessed:},
}

\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\nocite{*} % to get sources in the references.bib file without pages specified for working papers that use however page numbers in the footicite in text into the bibliography

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} 

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\slash} % no space between author seperation

% THE SECTION I AM MOSTLY CONCERNED ABOUT
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{1.3em}
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\footnote{\hangpara{1.635em}{1} #1}}
\newcommand{\fnt}[1]{\footnotetext{\hangpara{1.635em}{1} #1}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\onehalfspacing % \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\titleformat{\chapter} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{8pt}{} 
\titleformat{\section} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection.}{8pt}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: A MWE will be helpful, as that way we can test our suggestions. But I think instead of using the `hanging` package and manually interfere with how `\footnote` is typeset with your new commands, maybe it is easier to use the [`footmisc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc?lang=en) package loaded with the `hang` option?

Comment: Yes, please post an MWE. But please post a real example document (not just the preamble) and try to make it as minimal as possible (e.g. you don't need to load `tikz`, `booktabs`, `amsmath`, ...). Just make sure that it actually reproduces the behaviour you are asking about. The document class is usually very much involved in footnote formatting (though `footmisc` might make some of that irrelevant).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. As a LaTeX newbie this is really non-trivial for me. So I apologize deeply for posting my complete preamble as I cannot really determine what causes this behavior

Comment: A MWE is a piece of _compilable_ code that exhibits the problematic behavior. If you only post the preamble we cannot reproduce the problem without trying to fill in a lot of the blanks. That creates resistance for other people to help you. Your MWE doesn't have to truly minimal: do your best. For some help on how to produce a suitable MWE, see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: In the mean time, please test what happens if you *(1)* remove `\usepackage{hanging}` and remove the `\hangpara{...}{....}` from the definitions of the `\fn` and `\fnt` commands. *(2)* load `footmisc` with the addition of the `hang` option (so `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}`. **What you should look for**: does the indentation behavior of "normal foot notes" and "footnote citations" now look the same? Don't worry if the spacing is off, the key to check for is whether they two are consistent. If they are, then you can adjust the spacing using `footmisc` controls.

Comment: All right. I will take that to heart for the future. Meanwhile, your comment already helped me tremendously. It all looks consitent as postulated by you! Can you show me how I would increase in the indention away from the left margin, as now the footnotes are too "close" to the index. Additionally, do I have to replace all prior fnt and fn commands now with the baseline footnote and footnotetext as my LaTeX compiler now obviously states undefined control sequence